# How to create a Draft view with Content Moderation?

Tags: views, 8

In Drupal 7 with Workbench Moderation is easy to create a view to show the last Draft of a content:

[image]

You have a relation in the view named *Workbench Moderation: Node*, so using the filter *Workbench Moderation: Current (Yes)* is easy to create the view.

But in Drupal 8 with Content Moderation I can't find the way to have this working in a site with 2 languages.

[image]

**EDIT:**

If I use a relation to Content Moderation and Content revision I can access to the Moderation State and to the Latest Modification fields.

[image]

But if I make a Draft in the English version of the node I see in the view the French version as a Draft.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a filter of language?

Comment: @NoSssweat the problem is that I can have draft in english and in frech at the same time

Comment: Same problem for me. Have you solved it?

Comment: @AnishSheela I never found the answer and I'm not working now on this project. If you find a solution you can add it here as an answer.